# Preventing ransomware attacks by detecting suspicious levels of file system activity

Tags: security, file-management, acl, malware-detection

Assume a Windows 8/10 home/small office system with 3-4 users and a few TB of file share (say 6TB in a suitable RAID). Most files are static, but sometimes files get moved round or modified. But if overwriting/deleting starts to happen at too great a rate (number of files/sustained rate) it could be a sign of malicious activity and an event should be triggered to alert a user or respond to it.

If it were due to a ransomlocker style of attack, and the file modding can be detected and halted in the first 5/30 minutes the odds are fairly good that any damage will be localised or other backups may exist for the same/similar data, so it can be lived with. (My reason for this view is that it takes 10-20 hours just to stream a 4TB drive for copying locally; encrypting a 6TB RAID will be much slower due to constant read-write of the source drives)

<s>The problem is that file ACLs aren't intended for more than a binary "unlimited permission"/"zero permission". That doesn't work for other malware issues (bad attachments/downloads etc) and doesn't help here. I'd like some kind of ongoing "sanity check" on how much and what kind of activity is being done with that access. But I also don't want to slow down file handling when it is legitimate, unless actual suspicious access is detected.</s>

What kinds of techniques can be used so that if a malicious process somehow managed to get executed on the device or LAN, and began a cycle of high speed "read-modify-overwrite" or "read-savenewfile-deleteoriginal" on a device, the resulting file activity could be alerted by that device as suspicious?

So the target of detection is the insane flurry of file activity a ransomlocker-type attack would kick off.  It would be very hard to conceal, sustained, and very distinctive/abnormal. It should make ransomlocker style attacks the easiest to prevent. But how would one go about watching for it?

**Update:**

Sorry for any miswording. I've struck out the wording that led to it, as being a distraction - I thought it would be hepful. But the technicalities of ACL really are be off-topic here. The issue/question isn't "can you lock down your file system structure to avoid ransomware issues", *even if* you absolutely can do so.

The question is closer to this: *"You have a large Windows-based file system, but permissions either can't or won't be locked down (**for whatever reason, whether some might agree or disagree**).  In theory a ransomlocker attack would take many hours and generate unconcealable and extremely distinctive file system activity that, if noticed, would surely have the potential to allow effective action before the damage could become extreme. Ransomware activity is completely unmistakable, so extensive damage could be preventable by detecting and alerting this abnormal file system behaviour, even if the malware isn't detected. Question:  If such detection were desirable, what methods/tools/techniques can be used to detect the kind of activity involved?"*

Comment: **"The problem is that file ACLs aren't intended for more than a binary `unlimited permission`/`zero permission`"** - This is news to me.  This goes against, 3 separate objectives, on the CompTIA Security+ exam.

Comment: Side-issue but surely file ACLs are defined in terms of whether authorisation/account X can do action Y" - which is essentially binary. Not one ACL I've heard of is defined in terms of _how that access is used once verified to be allowed_ (the closest I can think of is quota enforcement but is that usually considered an ACL item?). If ACLs can establish more granular permissions for how a permission is used across the filesystem and not just granularity of which permissions may be used in what circumstances to which files, can you explain? Otherwise this comment seems off topic whether or not

Comment: I took offense to "unlimited" permission.  You certainly can restrict a group to read,write,execute. read & write, read & execute, read & write & execute, and for folder you could restrict to just listing the contents but none of the above.  So an ACl if properly configured could protect from ransomware, of course my personal believe, is the only safe data from ransomware is data that isn't connected at the time of infection.  So the best way to prevent that is not to get infected at all

Comment: @Ramhound,, I agree that locking down the filing system would do the job. But if locking down fully isn't an option, or the user wants layered security of both locking down and activity detection in case of escalation of privilege/issues relating to an administrator's access/other ACL bypass, then the question's main point is a valid one. I've added an update to clarify and focus the question, and struck out the para with the distraction.

Comment: file system monitoring, you could monitor your logs with many tools for uncommon amount of file deletions or creations, most encryption technics delete the file after encrypting it,
you can also try user behavior analytics this kind of tools focus on monitoring common user behaviour and alerting of any change in accepted behaviour, have a read to this https://blog.varonis.com/the-complete-ransomware-guide/

Comment: The article refers to a paper that says they "wrote a driver" to monitor activity. No reference to tools (other than usual event logs), and no "out there" tools identified as existing, just confirms viable which is already understood. Best answer/info so far but hoping for more concrete answers.